# Android 7,8 and Oxygen OS: Broadcast Receiver not working if app is killed

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

Post Android 7, my alarm receiver is not receiving the broadcast receiver if the app is killed by swiping it off from the recent tasks list.
Following is the piece from my AlarmReceiver, which extends BroadCastReceiver.

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(Constants.TAG, "event received");
        setContext(context);

        /* 
        *** My logic here *** 
        */

        Log.d(Constants.TAG, "alarm received");
    }
}
```

The place I am setting the alarm and registering the AlarmReceiver class for the alarm.

```
public class UnityNotificationManager
{
    public static void SetNotification(int id, long delayMs, String title, String message, String ticker, int sound, int vibrate,
                                       int lights, String largeIconResource, String smallIconResource, int bgColor, String bundle, String dataString)
    {
        Context currentActivity = UnityPlayer.currentActivity;
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)currentActivity.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        Intent intent = new Intent(Constants.ALARM_RECEIVER);
        intent.setClass(currentActivity, AlarmReceiver.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);

        intent.putExtra("ticker", ticker);
        intent.putExtra("title", title);
        intent.putExtra("message", message);
        intent.putExtra("id", id);
        intent.putExtra("color", bgColor);
        intent.putExtra("sound", sound == 1);
        intent.putExtra("vibrate", vibrate == 1);
        intent.putExtra("lights", lights == 1);
        intent.putExtra("l_icon", largeIconResource);
        intent.putExtra("s_icon", smallIconResource);
        intent.putExtra("bundle", bundle);
        intent.putExtra("dataString", dataString);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(currentActivity,
                id, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        am.cancel(pendingIntent);

        long finalTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + delayMs;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
            am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,finalTime, pendingIntent);
        } else {
            am.setAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,finalTime, pendingIntent);
        }
        Log.d(Constants.TAG, "event fired finalTime = "+ finalTime);
    }
}
```

The value of the above used `Constants.ALARM_RECEIVER` is same as the action name defined in manifest for the broadcast AlarmReceiver will listen to.

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.app.AlarmReceiver">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.app.alarm.action.trigger" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

The reason for using an explicit broadcast is that the android docs state that post Android Oreo, android applications won't be able to use implicit broadcasts in the background to improve performance. The link for the same: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html#broadcasts

I also tried using a WakefulBroadCastReceiver to avoid optimizations made by Doze mode on android devices, but it turns out that this class has been deprecated in Android Oreo. The link for the same: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html

The aforementioned code works for nearly every other manufacturer except One Plus devices, which run on oxygen os. Is there any way to fix this issue as notifications for applications like WhatsApp continue to work if app is killed the same way.

Additional Information:
1. I ran the command `adb shell dumpsys package <package_name> | grep stopped` on One Plus 5T and it returned the following output:

```
User 0: ceDataInode=2039857 installed=true hidden=false suspended=false stopped=false notLaunched=false enabled=0 instant=false
```

which, in turn suggests that the app is not stopped on swiping the app from the recent tasks list. Also, the "Force Stop" button is enabled on the application information page, suggesting that the app hasn't been force stopped.

2. I was able to make the notifications work if I manually changed the Battery Optimizations setting from 'Optimized' to 'Not Optimized', but since notifications for other applications worked even when they are in the Optimized state, I don't believe this to be the solution for my problem.

Can someone please suggest any fixes or work-arounds to fix the notification issue on devices running Android 7 or above on Oxygen OS?

Answer (score 2):

I have observed the same behaviour. The bug seems to be that Oxygen OS is not allowing the broadcast receiver to start from the PendingIntent. The solution was to use a Service instead on BroadcastReceiver.

Move your code from BroadcastReceiver's onReceive() to a Service's onStartCommand() method and then set this Service class in the PendingIntent.

```
...
intent.setClass(currentActivity, AlarmService.class);
...
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(currentActivity, id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
...
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

> Yes, I also found it hard to get reference sample codes, as 8.0 onwards there are restrictions on always running tasks.

---

Do not place any `intent-actions` in `Manifest.xml` like this :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name=".Receiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name=".CatchNumbers"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" />
    <service
        android:name=".WatchMan"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >

    </service>

    <activity android:name=".developer_activity" />
    <activity android:name=".WhiteListActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".Contacts" />
</application>
```

please note

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

are not inserted by me, android studio inserted it automatically when i registered runtime receiver in service. It is necessary.

---

From my receiver.java on every `boot_complete` i registers receivers runtime in a foreground service. It is must if you want your receiver to work :

```
package com.example.rushi.instapromo;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    Log.d("BootTest : ", "\nOnBootReceiver - Received a broadcast!");
    Toast.makeText(context, "OnBootReceiver Received a broadcast!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    {
        context.startForegroundService(new Intent(context, WatchMan.class));
    }
    else
    {
        context.startService(new Intent(context, WatchMan.class));
    }
}
}
```

Note that Watchman.java is foreground service which registers runtime receiver, if you do not go with this method, it will never work. I have tried a lot and invented this is the way only.

---

Register receivers in foreground service like

```
public class WatchMan extends Service
{
NotificationManager mNotifyManager;
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;
NotificationChannel notificationChannel;
String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "17";

private BroadcastReceiver mCallBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        String PhoneNumber = "UNKNOWN";
        Log.d("RECEIVER :  ","IS UP AGAIN....");

        try
        {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"))
            {
                if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))
                {
                    PhoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                    Log.d("RECEIVER : ","Incoming number : "+PhoneNumber);

                    // update in database and goto catchnumber to sms

                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
                    {
                        context.startForegroundService(new Intent(context, CatchNumbers.class));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        context.startService(new Intent(context, CatchNumbers.class));
                    }
                }
                if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE))
                {
                    PhoneNumber = "UNKNOWN";
                }
                if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK))
                {
                    Log.d("RECEIVER :  ","OUTGOING CALL RECEIVED....");

                    // UPDATED in database and JUST GOTO catchnumber to sms

                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
                    {
                        context.startForegroundService(new Intent(context, CatchNumbers.class));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        context.startService(new Intent(context, CatchNumbers.class));
                    }
                }
            }
            if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"))
            {
                PhoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
                Log.d("RECEIVER : ","Outgoing number : "+PhoneNumber);

                // update in database and BUT DO NOT GOTO catchnumber to sms
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("RECEIVER : ", "Exception is : ", e);
        }
    }
};

public WatchMan() { }

@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    super.onCreate();
    Log.d("WatchMan : ", "\nOnCreate...");

    IntentFilter CallFilter = new IntentFilter();
    CallFilter.addAction("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL");
    CallFilter.addAction("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE");
    this.registerReceiver(mCallBroadcastReceiver, CallFilter);

    Log.d("WatchMan : ", "\nmCallBroadcastReceiver Created....");

    mNotifyManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, null);
    mBuilder.setContentTitle("Insta Promo")
            .setContentText("InstaPromo Service ready")
            .setTicker("InstaPromo Service ready")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setAutoCancel(false);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    {
        notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "My Notifications", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

        // Configure the notification channel.
        notificationChannel.setDescription("Channel description");
        notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
        notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
        notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0, 1000, 500, 1000});
        notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
        notificationChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
        mNotifyManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);

        mBuilder.setChannelId(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
        startForeground(17, mBuilder.build());
    }
    else
    {
        mBuilder.setChannelId(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
        //startForeground(17, mBuilder.build());
        mNotifyManager.notify(17, mBuilder.build());
    }
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    Log.d("WatchMan : ", "\nmCallBroadcastReceiver Listening....");

    //return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    this.unregisterReceiver(mCallBroadcastReceiver);
    Log.d("WatchMan : ", "\nDestroyed....");
    Log.d("WatchMan : ", "\nWill be created again....");
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
{
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}
}
```

---

Please note how i registered and unregistered `NEW_OUTGOING_CALL`  and `PHONE_STATE` intent actions. `CatchNumbers` is another `service` which i am using to do whatever i want to with incoming and outgoing numbers.

---

> Your intent actions might be different than me.., But this is the only way if you want it to implement in 8.0 onwards. Tested and and i am working with this code. It supports 4.2 to Android P api level 29 also. On every reboot these 2 intent filters and receivers are ready fro me to use in my `CatchNumbers`. Hope it really helps you. or some one else.

Comment: Yes, it also works if user swipes away app activity from recents... tested on 4.2 to android p emulators and actual devices

Comment: If you do not want your activity in recents use android:excludeFromRecents="true" for your mainactivity in xml. But this is not the solution.